# Passing 2d arrays and then not getting a value

Tags: c, pointers, multidimensional-array

I am having an issue with some code that I am writing.
I use this site often as I have found many people who have already asked the same questions I am wondering. With that I want to thank the community on here for all of the previous insight into my programming conundrums.
(And before we get too far, no this is not a 'school project' or 'school homework', I am simply trying to solve the 'Travelling Salesman Problem' and better my C skills.

This is the portion of code I have been stuck on:

```
   void printAndFlip(int arrayone[][20], int citytotal, int arrayCities[])
   {

////Finds cost:
int x, y, z;
int totalCost
int singleTrip;
int cheepestTrip;
int nCity = citytotal + 1;      //nCity is the number of Cities //Adding one to accomadate going back to the first city
int gCounter;
int gCounterTrue = 1;
int cheepestTrip[20];
int totalCost = 0;
int lCounter;
int i;
int n = citytotal;


////Sets up for a default case to set cheepestTrip:
for(gCounter = 1; gCounter <= nCity; gCounter++)
{
    while(gCounterTrue == 1)
    {
        if(gCounter == arrayCities[gCounter])
        {
            gCounterTrue = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            gCounterTrue = 0;
            gCounter = 50;      //Stopping the larger for loop with 50 (the nCity can't be larger than 20) so that it will hopefully be faster
        }
        if(gCounter == nCity)
        {
            if(arrayCities[1] == arrayCities[nCity])
            {
!!!!!               cheepestTrip = totalCost;
            }
        }   
    }
}
for(x = 1; x < nCity; x++)
{
    y = arrayCities[x];
    z = arrayCities[x+1];
    singleTrip = arrayone[y][z];        //finding individual cost of each trip...will be added to 'totalCost' below
    totalCost = singleTrip + totalCost;
} 

!!!!!!!!  if(totalCost <= cheepestTrip)
{
    for(lCounter = 1; lCounter <= nCity; lCounter++)
    {
        cheepestTrip[lCounter] = arrayCities[lCounter];
    }
}
```

To make it easier to show where my compile errors are at I put exclamation points on the lines.
Please tell me if I am wrong, but I am passing an array of pointers with an array when I send 'arrayone' to printANDFlip right?
I know the compile errors are relating to the pointers but I am just uncertain of where they should be placed.
Any and all help will be appreciated.
Much thanks,
Alex

Comment: I have proposed a Q&A site for beginner programmers. Where simple questions should be met with a positive attitude and to encourage people to learn to be better programmers. If you like the idea follow the proposal http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/52242/beginner-programmers?referrer=YHFcRobXPDGfDpFmz1HCvA2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make explicit what some of the other replies are saying: You have two variables with the same name but different types:

```
int cheepestTrip;  /* This is an single integer... */
```

and

```
int cheepestTrip[20];  /* ...but this is an array of integers. */
```

This should be triggering a warning at compile time (probably something about redeclaring an existing variable).

Comment: Oh my gosh! I spent three hours trying to figure this out! I can not believe it was that simple!!!  Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Here you are comparing an array pointer with a int value

```
if(totalCost <= cheepestTrip)
```

For example you should compare it to an element of that array

```
  if(totalCost <= cheepestTrip[0])
```

Answer (score 1):

`cheepestTrip` is the name of the array, which is equivalent to a pointer to the first element. `totalCost` is an `int`. Just remove the `[20]` from your declaration at the top part of the code.

Answer (score 0):

you are comparing a pointer to an int, which your particular compiler might not be allowing (though I though with C you could). but cheapestTrip is essentially a pointer to the first element in your array of ints, while totalcost is simply an int primative